# How come Java has two color values for each color?

Tags: java

How come Java has two java.awt.Color values for each of its preset colors? It has one with the first letter capitalized and another in all uppercase. I made a test class that prints out the two values of the colors to see if they are different.

```
import java.awt.Color;
public class test{
   public static void main(String[] args){
       System.out.println("white is: "+Color.white+" and WHITE is: "+Color.WHITE);
   }
}
```

This prints out the same result. So why does java have two values that are exactly the same?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The constants in lowercase are synonyms with the ones in uppercase. And for the record, the ones in lowercase were goofs - the coding convention mandates that constants should have all-uppercase names, this was fixed starting with version 1.4 of Java; it's weird that they haven't been marked as deprecated after all this time. I guess they remain there just for backwards compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Compatibility with older versions; the upper case letters were introduced in JDK 1.4.

Answer (score 1):

**white**
public static final Color white
The color white. In the default sRGB space.

**WHITE**
public static final Color WHITE
The color white. In the default sRGB space.
**Since:
1.4**

**So only difference is with version WHITE  was introduced in 1.4 version of jdk** 
 white is in existence only to support old systems compatibility
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#white

Answer (score 0):

```
Color.white.equals(Color.WHITE);
```

IS TRUE.